# captionsetup for margin caption

Tags: captions, marginpar

I am using the caption package to set up the layout of my captions. However for margin captions using mcaption package the `\captionsetup` does not seem to have the expected effect.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}[2011/08/06]
\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\captionsetup{format=plain}
\captionsetup[margincap]{name=Fig.,
  indention=0pt,justification=RaggedRight}
\begin{document}

Pellentesque mollis nunc sed mauris tempor molestie. Aliquam adipiscing nisi

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{margincap}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/TestBild}
  \caption[short caption text]{long caption text with some more 
   text and a bit more text and a little more text to fill space.}
  \label{fig:picmargincap}
\end{margincap}
\end{figure}

Pellentesque mollis nunc sed mauris tempor molestie. Aliquam adipiscing nisi
\end{document}
```

The 'Figure' should be abbrevitated to 'Fig.' but it is not:

[image]

Comment: You can even say `\captionsetup[sesame street]{...}` but this will only save the `sesame street` options for later use. As long as no-one is calling `\caption@setoptions{sesame street}` or `\captionsetup{options=sesame street}` this will have no effect. So if you would like to get this work I would drop a mail to the `mcaption` package maintainer, asking for inserting something like `\@ifundefined{caption@setoptions}{}{\caption@setoptions{margincap}}` into his package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`margincap` is not a floating environment:

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{name=Fig.,
  indention=0pt,justification=RaggedRight}
\begin{margincap}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/TestBild}
  \caption[short caption text]{long caption text with some more
   text and a bit more text and a little more text to fill space.}
  \label{fig:picmargincap}
\end{margincap}
\end{figure}
```

With

```
\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\margincap{\captionsetup{name=Fig.,%
  indention=0pt,justification=RaggedRight}}
```

you can avoid setting the modification in the `figure` environment.

Following Axel Sommerfeldt's suggestion, one can better define a new option:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\margincap{\captionsetup{options=margincap}}

\captionsetup[margincap]{name=Fig.,%
  indention=0pt,justification=RaggedRight}}
```

Comment: What about `\preto\margincap{\captionsetup{options=margincap}}` ? This way `\captionsetup[margincap]{...}` will have the desired effect.

Answer (score 7):

[`mcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/margincap)'s `margincap` uses the same counter as the traditional `figure` environments, namely `figure`. From the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mcaption/mcaption.pdf) (p 1, section **2 Usage**):

> Caption text and the label are taken from `\caption` and `\label`
>   commands within the environment.

As such, the following produces the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}[2011/08/06]
\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\captionsetup{format=plain}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig.,
  indention=0pt,justification=RaggedRight}
\begin{document}

Pellentesque mollis nunc sed mauris tempor molestie. Aliquam adipiscing nisi

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{margincap}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/TestBild}
  \caption[short caption text]{long caption text with some more 
   text and a bit more text and a little more text to fill space.}
  \label{fig:picmargincap}
\end{margincap}
\end{figure}

Pellentesque mollis nunc sed mauris tempor molestie. Aliquam adipiscing nisi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, but I do not want this setting to be applied to all captions.

Comment: Wellll...... this request wasn't included in the question.